# How do you export a Pandas DataFrame (to_csv) such that the categorical objects within it remain categorical?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I've been working on a machine learning problem that involves converting string data in a pandas DataFrame to a `pd.Categorical` object.

Here's how I've done that:

```
import pandas as pd
df_temp = pd.read_csv('data/Train.csv',low_memory=False)


# This will turn all of the string values into categorical values
for label, content in df_temp.items():
    if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(content.dropna()):
        df_temp[label] = content.astype('category')
```

Before the above block of code, `df_temp.dtypes` returns...

```
SalesID                                 int64
SalePrice                               int64
MachineID                               int64
ModelID                                 int64
datasource                              int64
auctioneerID                          float64
YearMade                                int64
MachineHoursCurrentMeter              float64
UsageBand                              object
fiModelDesc                            object
fiBaseModel                            object
fiSecondaryDesc                        object
fiModelSeries                          object
fiModelDescriptor                      object
ProductSize                            object
fiProductClassDesc                     object
state                                  object
ProductGroup                           object
ProductGroupDesc                       object
Drive_System                           object
Enclosure                              object
Forks                                  object
Pad_Type                               object
Ride_Control                           object
Stick                                  object
Transmission                           object
Turbocharged                           object
Blade_Extension                        object
Blade_Width                            object
Enclosure_Type                         object
Engine_Horsepower                      object
Hydraulics                             object
Pushblock                              object
Ripper                                 object
Scarifier                              object
Tip_Control                            object
Tire_Size                              object
Coupler                                object
Coupler_System                         object
Grouser_Tracks                         object
Hydraulics_Flow                        object
Track_Type                             object
Undercarriage_Pad_Width                object
Stick_Length                           object
Thumb                                  object
Pattern_Changer                        object
Grouser_Type                           object
Backhoe_Mounting                       object
Blade_Type                             object
Travel_Controls                        object
Differential_Type                      object
Steering_Controls                      object
dateYear                                int64
dateMonth                               int64
dateDay                                 int64
dateDayOfWeek                           int64
dateDayOfYear                           int64
auctioneerIDis_missing                   bool
MachineHoursCurrentMeteris_missing       bool
dtype: object
```

After running the code, `df_temp.dtypes` returns this:

```
SalesID                                  int64
SalePrice                                int64
MachineID                                int64
ModelID                                  int64
datasource                               int64
auctioneerID                           float64
YearMade                                 int64
MachineHoursCurrentMeter               float64
UsageBand                             category
fiModelDesc                           category
fiBaseModel                           category
fiSecondaryDesc                       category
fiModelSeries                         category
fiModelDescriptor                     category
ProductSize                           category
fiProductClassDesc                    category
state                                 category
ProductGroup                          category
ProductGroupDesc                      category
Drive_System                          category
Enclosure                             category
Forks                                 category
Pad_Type                              category
Ride_Control                          category
Stick                                 category
Transmission                          category
Turbocharged                          category
Blade_Extension                       category
Blade_Width                           category
Enclosure_Type                        category
Engine_Horsepower                     category
Hydraulics                            category
Pushblock                             category
Ripper                                category
Scarifier                             category
Tip_Control                           category
Tire_Size                             category
Coupler                               category
Coupler_System                        category
Grouser_Tracks                        category
Hydraulics_Flow                       category
Track_Type                            category
Undercarriage_Pad_Width               category
Stick_Length                          category
Thumb                                 category
Pattern_Changer                       category
Grouser_Type                          category
Backhoe_Mounting                      category
Blade_Type                            category
Travel_Controls                       category
Differential_Type                     category
Steering_Controls                     category
dateYear                                 int64
dateMonth                                int64
dateDay                                  int64
dateDayOfWeek                            int64
dateDayOfYear                            int64
auctioneerIDis_missing                    bool
MachineHoursCurrentMeteris_missing        bool
dtype: object
```

Additionally, I can access the categorical attributes and use the categorial methods of each categorical feature. For example, you can run `df_temp.state.cat.codes` without an error.

So, it appears that pandas is propperly converting the string data to categorical data. This exactly what I would have it do.

The problem comes when I try to export this data to a cvs file (using `pd.to_csv`) and then re-import it using (`pd.read_csv`).

Here's my code for that:

```
# Export current df_temp dataframe
df_temp.to_csv('data/temp_train.csv',
              index=False)
```

This line of code executes sucessfully. I can then re import it using the following code:

```
df_temp = pd.read_csv('data/temp_train.csv',
                low_memory=False)
```

This code likewise runs just fine. However, the problem comes when I try access the catagorical atributes or use catagorical methods the features of the DataFrame that should be catagorical in the re-imported DataFrame. For example, running `df_temp.state.cat.codes` returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype
```

Further, when I look at `df_temp.dtypes`, it returns this:

```
SalesID                                 int64
SalePrice                               int64
MachineID                               int64
ModelID                                 int64
datasource                              int64
auctioneerID                          float64
YearMade                                int64
MachineHoursCurrentMeter              float64
UsageBand                              object
fiModelDesc                            object
fiBaseModel                            object
fiSecondaryDesc                        object
fiModelSeries                          object
fiModelDescriptor                      object
ProductSize                            object
fiProductClassDesc                     object
state                                  object
ProductGroup                           object
ProductGroupDesc                       object
Drive_System                           object
Enclosure                              object
Forks                                  object
Pad_Type                               object
Ride_Control                           object
Stick                                  object
Transmission                           object
Turbocharged                           object
Blade_Extension                        object
Blade_Width                            object
Enclosure_Type                         object
Engine_Horsepower                      object
Hydraulics                             object
Pushblock                              object
Ripper                                 object
Scarifier                              object
Tip_Control                            object
Tire_Size                              object
Coupler                                object
Coupler_System                         object
Grouser_Tracks                         object
Hydraulics_Flow                        object
Track_Type                             object
Undercarriage_Pad_Width                object
Stick_Length                           object
Thumb                                  object
Pattern_Changer                        object
Grouser_Type                           object
Backhoe_Mounting                       object
Blade_Type                             object
Travel_Controls                        object
Differential_Type                      object
Steering_Controls                      object
dateYear                                int64
dateMonth                               int64
dateDay                                 int64
dateDayOfWeek                           int64
dateDayOfYear                           int64
auctioneerIDis_missing                   bool
MachineHoursCurrentMeteris_missing       bool
```

It seems to me that pandas is not exporting the DataFrame to csv file with all of the infromation that comes with a categorical object. It appears that it is just exporting the string equivellent of the catagory. How could I get it to export the catagorical objects as catagorical objects instead of converting them to strings and then exporting them?

Ideally, after exporting and re-importing the DataFrame from the CSV file, it would behave in exactly the same way as it did before importing it. I would like `df_temp.dtypes` to return

```
SalesID                                  int64
SalePrice                                int64
MachineID                                int64
ModelID                                  int64
datasource                               int64
auctioneerID                           float64
YearMade                                 int64
MachineHoursCurrentMeter               float64
UsageBand                             category
fiModelDesc                           category
fiBaseModel                           category
fiSecondaryDesc                       category
fiModelSeries                         category
fiModelDescriptor                     category
ProductSize                           category
fiProductClassDesc                    category
state                                 category
...
```

and to be able to immediately access the categorical attributes of these categorical features, e.g., `df_temp.state.cat.codes`.

I've looked at the documentation for `pd.to_csv` and `pd.read_csv` to see if there were any parameters I could change to get it to maintain the categorical nature of the categorical entries, but I did not find anything.

I suppose it might work if I exported and re-imported the DataFrame object with a library like Pickle or Joblib, but I'd prefer to keep the data in CSV format as much as possible.

Comment: csv is a lossy format. It cannot store metadata. You can store the column dtypes separately and then read that and pass the dtypes to `read_csv` to the `dtype` param

Comment: A non-pickle alternative (if you're open to non-csv files) is parquet which stores metadata

Comment: @AsishM. Thanks! I tried both methods, and they both worked. I like the parquet way best, but it's good to know the other way as well.